# pandas.pivot_table generates wrong sums

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, xlsx

I have stumbled upon a strange phenomenon...

I have a working code to generate pivoted tables from data uploaded from excels. I have stumbled on a strange case where after applying pivot_table to the data, I get different summed values than before pivot...

I generate data from `xlsx` and `xls` files, do some stuff with it and then want to generate a pivoted table. Before the pivot I do `df.VAL1.sum()` and `df.VAL2.sum()` and the values are the same ones as the ones summed in excels using `=sum()`, but after I run my `pd.pivot_table()` code I get a different result when I do `pivot.sum()`

The data has the following columns:

```
COL1 COL2 COL3 time_period VAL1 VAL2 UNIT_VAL1 COL4 COL5 COL6 UNIT_VAL2 COL7 COL8 COL9
```

where `time_period` is a string - `YYYY-MM`

and here is the pivot_table attributes:

```
pivot = pd.pivot_table(
    df[[
        'COL1', 'COL2', 'COL3', 'COL9', 'time_period',
        'VAL1','COL8', 'COL4', 'COL5', 'COL6', 'COL7', 'UNIT_VAL'
    ]],
    values='VAL1',
    columns='time_period',
    index=[
        'COL7', 'COL8', 'COL3', 'COL1',
        'COL5', 'COL2', 'COL9',
        'COL4', 'COL6', 'UNIT_VAL'
    ],
    aggfunc=np.sum
)
```

Can the string `time_period` be the problem here or the order of the passed column names? Or maybe I am doing something wrong here? I want to note that this happens only with 2 dataframes, as other dataframes work well.

If the problem is not in code but with my data, then I'll close or delete the question.

Comment: Still haven't found the issue - the only thing I observed, that `np.sum` does some `magic` with decimals - the sums after 4 decimal spaces... but this should not change the data in millions IMHO...

Comment: Can you take just a few rows of your data and share here? Removing any sensitive information etc.

Comment: unfortunately not...

Comment: I understand, but that means there is no scope to help much further. I would suggest cutting down your input data to a few rows and repeat the process, try to find the offending row.

Comment: I think I might've found something. I'm using `np.sum` and numpy uses floats. Probably i have huge numbers there (in Bilions + couple decimal spaces) so that might be the problem